# Ruby on Rails + devise: How can i create customize users table with devis rake db:migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

rails generate devise User I got this=>

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable

      # t.encryptable
      # t.confirmable
      # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
      # t.token_authenticatable


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

But i want to create a users table with username, email, password, role, group, mark, created_at, modified_at columns.

How can i do this ?

Is this structure correct to have username, password, email, group, role, mark ?

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable

      # t.encryptable
      # t.confirmable
      # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
      # t.token_authenticatable

      t.string :username
      t.string :password
      t.string :email
      t.string :group
      t.string :role
      t.integer :mark

      t.timestamps
  end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

What are these?

```
t.database_authenticatable :null => false
          t.recoverable
          t.rememberable
          t.trackable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a migration to add some fields to the user table.
For example:

```
rails g add_fields_to_users username:string # as well as other fields you need
```

Then, in order to add columns to your table run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Devise has already generated some columns you need like: email, password, created_at, updated_at...

For adding roles to your user model you should watch the cancan screencast: [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) and also read the [doc](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) in order to see some updates.

**EDIT:**

If you want to add fields manually you could add them in your self.up method before running your migration:

```
def self.up
  create_table(:users) do |t|

    #...

    t.rememberable
    t.trackable

    t.string :username
    #... your other attributes here

  end
```

Comment: I don't want to add columns from command line or terminal , how can i edit that file to have those columns ? Can you post the your edited DeviseCreateUsers file ?

Comment: Not really :) You have to look at the devise doc in order to understand which modules do for you. (you can also read things in the book rails 3 in action where every devise modules is explained) With devise_authenticable you have already password and email fields set so you just have to add username and the others.

Comment: You could also see what fields devise generate through a db browser. It could be useful The Devise doc are there: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Where is password and email fields are set ? How can i be sure that email and password are set. I don't see those email and password field in that migration file .

Comment: It's clearly higher of my knowledge but you could look at these files responsible to set your email and password: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb and https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb